# When is "se" used before a verb?

Tags: traducción, gramática

I'm confused about when "se" should be used. I thought it would always go before a like here:

> Ella se mejora a su coche

but I see here that it is *not* being used.

> Él observa a su hija

My question is, when is `se` used before the verb?

Comment: [Usage 1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs#1), [Usage 2](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs#2)

Comment: @EmilioGort Sorry, I'm not able to read that as my spanish is not good.

Comment: Sorry my english isnt good enough to explain, I think someone look into the links and he/she will explain in an answer

Comment: "Ella se mejora a su coche" is probably not the best example in terms of what is being improved, "ella" or "coche"?  Maybe, "Ella se mejora cuando pasea en su coche"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emilio's links are correct.

I will focus on the wide use of `se` as reflexive.

`Se` can be translated as the third person pronoun, like the reflexive pronouns `himself, herself, itself, themselves`.

1. Él/Ella se mejora su coche --> He/She improved his/her car
   himself/herself
2. ¡La mesa se mueve sola! ¡Es magia! --> The table moves itself! It's
       magic!
3. Se alimentaron en el restaurante --> They fed themselves at the
   restaurant

In your first example you can drop the reflexive pronoun and everybody will understand you, it is just extra information.

In the second example you mention:

> Él observa a su hija --> He watches her daughter.

You are asking about *Él se observa a su hija*

`Se` is indirect of the person who is doing the action (`Él`).

*Él se observa a su hija* --> He watches by himself to her daughter / He watches her daughter (by) himself.

I am not English but it sounds a bit strange to add `himself` here. In English I remember you can use `himself / by himself / for himself` but here it is useless. You can apply the same thing to Spanish.

I think I won't be wrong if I ask you to put in these sentences the pronoun *themselves*.

*Las enfermeras están vigilando a los chicos --> The nurses are watching the children.*

1. Las enfermeras se están vigilando a los chicos (not correct) -->The
   nurses themselves are watching the children (Watching includes the
   nurses on the action, you do not need the pronoun)
2. Las enfermeras están vigilando a los chicos por sí mismas --> The
   nurses are watching the children by themselves. (Correct... but they are nurses
   everybody knows the children will be ok, they are capable of, do you really need it on both sentences? )

`Se` has several uses, if you are learning Spanish in the future the other uses of `se` will become familiar to you but right now as a starting point I think it is enough to know its use as reflexive pronoun, it is quite usual.

For other uses you can use this website [http://spanish.about.com/](http://spanish.about.com/cs/verbs/a/passive_se.htm)

> *Se venden oro y plata*, although translated literally would mean "gold and silver sell themselves," can be understood to mean "gold and silver are sold" or even "gold and silver for sale," neither of which specify who is doing the selling. *Se sirve desayuno* means "breakfast is served." And *se alquila*, which might be seen as a sign on a building or object, means simply "for rent."

*I am learning English so this answer can contain errors when it comes about translations and different uses of pronouns in English examples*

Comment: Question: I sometimes see sentences that start with "Me tengo" and some that start with just "Tengo". When should I use "Me tengo" instead of just "Tengo"?

Comment: "Ella se mejora a su coche" is probably not the best example in terms of what is being improved, "ella" or "coche"? Maybe, "Ella se mejora cuando pasea en su coche"? If what is being improved is the car, you would write "Ella mejora su coche".

Answer (score 9):

**SE Reflexivo.**

> El reflexivo significa que la misma persona que hace la acción la recibe.

`suicidarse`, `especializarse`, `arrepentirse de`, `asombrarse de`, `atreverse a`, `burlarse de`, `darse cuenta de`, `empeñarse en`, `enterarse de equivocarse`, `portarse bien / mal`, `resignarse`, `quejarse`

> Hay otros que conocemos como reflexivos pero también pueden ser
>   transitivos, es decir pasar su acción a otra cosa o persona.

`Cambiarse`, `vestirse`, `lavarse`, `cepillarse`

> Me cambio todos los días y cambio mi dinero en el banco.

`Aburrirse`, `alegrarse`, `cansarse`, `enojarse`, `divertirse`, `molestarse`, `preocuparse`, `interesarse`, `sorprenderse`, `asustarse`, `entristecerse`, `enfermarse`, `hincharse`, `mejorarse`, `curarse`, `pararse`, `sentarse`, `acostarse`, etc.

> También están los que nos indican un consumo total de algo.

`Tomarse`, `comerse`, `beberse`, `devorarse`.

Reflexive verbs are, in my opinion, the easiest `se` to grasp.  Translated to English, a sentence with a reflexive verb will have the word `self` in there somewhere, and if not, the sentence will indeed express some kind of emotion.  In English, we say that we want to `Take a bath/shower` when in Spanish you would bathe or shower yourself... or someone else even.  `Quiero ducharme` -- `I want to take a shower.`

At the bottom of the list above are some other reflexives that do not express emotion, but rather, consumption of some kind, whether it be yourself or something else, a consumption of ... all of it... as the quote says.

> nos indican un consumo total de algo

Example..

> - We're eating all of the pizza / Nos comemos la pizza
> - He drank the whole thing! / ¡Él se lo tomó!.

**SE Recíproco.**

> Implica una acción y dos personas realizándola al mismo tiempo.( Ellos= se).

`amarse`, `quererse`, `llamarse`, `verse`, `besarse`, `abrazarse`, `admirarse`, `tocarse`, `odiarse`

I would call this the opposite of a Reflexive verb.  These are personal verbs that involve another subject, as the definition suggests.

**SE Accidental.**

> Se usa para expresar la realización de una acción de manera accidental
>   o donde el sujeto no quiere asumir la responsabilidad.

`Romperse`, `perderse`, `olvidarse`, `caerse`, `quemarse`, `doblarse`, `quebrarse`, `abrirse` , `descomponerse`

In the Spanish language, for some reason, they do not accept the blame.  You don't forget your wallet, your wallet forgets you.  It's strange, but it's true.

**SE Impersonal.**

> Lo usamos cuando no sabemos o no queremos o no importa quien hace la
>   acción, sirve para expresar generalizaciones. Comúnmente aparece en la
>   tercera persona singular con verbos intransitivos sin embargo también
>   aparecen con algunos transitivos que se toman como “impersonales”.

```
Intransitivo. Se vive bien en Querétaro 
Transitivo. Se habla español en México.
```

You will often hear this usage when you are asked how to say something.

> ¿Cómo se dice ... potato... en español?`

Using English as an example you can see the trend used in this form of SE.

In English, we use "they" or "you" a lot to explain instructions, or advertisements, or, mainly, just to generalize... in some cases, "we"... as in `We sell furniture`... translated to `Se vende muebles`.

Other English examples -- in spanish.

> We speak Spanish (like the signs outside of a business)
>
> **Se habla español**
>
> You open it with a fork (instructions)
>
> **Se la abre con tenedor**
>
> They say the homework is hard (generalize)
>
> **Se dice es dificil la tarea**
>
> You don't say it like that (instructions)
>
> **No se lo dice así**

This impersonal "se" is a bit tricky to get used to.  I still use it incorrectly to this day, even after 15+ years of practice and education.

*Taken from my Advanced Spanish Manual, written by Veronica Martinez of ITESM Querétaro.*

Comment: +1 for the number of examples. On accidental and impersonal "se", I would say it's a trick we use in Spanish to avoid naming the subject. I would also mention that, when we use this trick, the direct object becomes the subject, i.e.: "[yo] rompí el vaso" becomes "el vaso se rompió"

Comment: Exactly.  To hide the subject.  Those Spaniards and their sneaky language!  `¡Él se lo tomó!` and `Se lo tomó` have two different meanings, one of which hides the subject, leaving the translation for the second example to be "It was drunk", a very vague and innocent statement.

Comment: I'm afraid "tomarse" is an example of reflexive "se" :) as "ducharse" and "lavarse". It translates better into "I got drunk", that is, I'm the only one to blame for getting drunk :p. "Me ducho" is "I take a shower", that is, "I wash myself"

Comment: If you actually read this list, you would see tomarse at the bottom of the SE Reflexivo list.  If I have to think of it lierally, I think of `to take on`.  If you `take on` a responsibility, you have all of that responsibility.  At the end of the day, all tomar really means is to `take`.. to receive.. to obtain... to consume... they all represent having the weight of something bestowed onto you, physically, orally, audibly even..  `Tomarse en cuenta` can have the same meaning as enfocarse, darse cuenta de, haber hecho caso... and more.

Comment: Do you mean "se lo tomó" as in "he drank it"? Yes, in that case, "se lo tomó" is an example of "hiding" the subject.

Comment: I do mean it in that way, Nico.  But it can also mean `It was drunk`.. as in .. someone drank it, someone took it, someone consumed it, and so on.  Just like `La bebida se toma` means `The drink is drank`, `The drink is being drank`, `Someone is drinking the drink` and then there is the impersonal 'se' making it `You drink the drink` ( an instruction ).  It all depends on the context in the end.

Comment: "You don't forget your wallet, your wallet forgets you. It's strange, but it's true.". Well this is actually incorrect. "Olvidé la cartera" or "Se me olvidó la cartera" translate literally to "I forgot my wallet"

Comment: I don't know if @dockeryZ is attempting to be intentionally slangy and/or humorous with "The drink is drank," but those who wish to use standard English would write instead, "The drink is drunk."  It is what is called the present simple passive.  For examples of this and others, visit: https://www.coachella.com/forum/showthread.php?41493-Drink-Drank-Drunk-A-lesson-in-grammar.  I'm sure you could find more authoritative sources out there if you look.  Also, if you have a source that claims, "The drink is drank," is standard English, please let us know!

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add some additional examples to maybe help clear your confusion of when to use *se* or when not to use, coming from a native speaker.

As others have already mentioned, the main use of "se" is reflexive. Compare/contrast the meaning of the following examples:

- *Él se da la vuelta.* vs *Él da la vuelta.*
- *Ella se mira en el espejo/la televisión/etc.* vs *Ella mira el espejo/la televisión/etc.*
- *Él se avienta a la alberca.* vs *Él avienta la pelota.*

A more complicated example could be something that is inherently reflexive, like

- *Él se come la pizza.* vs *Él come la pizza.*,

but I would argue that the fact these two statements express is the same, perhaps with only a slight change in emphasis. I hope these examples helped clear some of your confusion up.

Comment: Could you provide their translations?

Comment: Literally, number one translates into *He gives/goes around himself*, which means *He spins [around].* vs *He gives/goes around*, which can mean *He takes a walk/goes for a drive.* or anything similar, depending on context. Number 2 means *She looks at herself in the mirror/TV.* vs *She looks at the mirror/TV.* And Number 3, literally *He throws himself to the pool.* which I would translate as *He jumps into the pool.*, vs *He throws the ball.* My goal with these examples was to contrast the reflexive function *se* adds to the sentence so that it becomes clearer when you want to use it or not.

Comment: I wouldn't call *comerse* inherently reflexive.  A better example of something inherently reflexive might be *arrepentirse*, which obligates the reflexive pronoun — always.  You can't just say *él arrepintió* or *ella le arrepintió*, it must be *se arrepinitió*.